# PhpStorm: set file type for a single file

Tags: ide, phpstorm

I've inherited a project where all Smarty template (should be .tpl) are named .html

Problem is that there are html files also, so I can't globally redefine .html to always be smarty. Also, with 10 years+ of legacy code, I can't just rename the file.

Is there anyway I can get PhpStorm to recognize a single file (or a directory) as another format then the file name?

Comment: Nope (unless those file names have some unique suffix/prefix in their names so that you can create some unique pattern from that). Your only option right now is to re-assign `*.html` pattern to actual "Smarty files" in File Types. Yes -- it will affect all projects, so if you need to work with `*.html` files as actual HTML in another project -- you will have to re-assign it back.

Comment: The only other possible option is to have additional  IDE config stored in completely different location (e.g. `~/.WebIde80` is standard and your special could be in `~/.WebIde80-special`). Now you can use such IDE installation just for that project only.

Comment: Links for 2nd suggestion: 1) https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/23348963-Changing-IDE-default-directories-used-for-config-plugins-and-caches-storage 2) https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/23358108-Directories-used-by-the-IDE-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better late than never: there is an option in the file's contextmenu (right mousebutton) where you can set the type for one (or multiple files). rest is self explaining.

[image: right click]